# How to find shortcut exist on page using jquery?

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I added shortcut key on my control using jquery.

```
 $(function() {
      shortcut.add("ctrl+r", function() { SomeFunctionHere(); });

    });
```

how can i find that this key already added in my control?

Comment: Are you using [this library](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
if ('ctrl+r' in shortcut.all_shortcuts) {
    //Shortcut exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, shortcut.add() is not a jQuery library function.. what are you doing? Try this: http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/